# Configure Session Timeout Dialog without Logout Now button

Tags: jquery, session, asp.net-4.0

I am using JillElaine's JQuery Session timeout dialog pop out for displaying the Timeout alert on my .aspx page. Its working fine, but I don;t wanna give user an option of Logging out now and remove the Log out now button of this control.

Its not listed in configurable variables for that plug in . Does anybody know how to use that.
[here](https://github.com/JillElaine/jquery-idleTimeout) is github link for plugin itself.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the 'Log Out Now' button, you can directly edit the **unminified** .js code file: **jquery-idleTimeout.js** or **jquery-idleTimeout-iframes.js**.

In the code section commented with

`//----------- WARNING DIALOG FUNCTIONS --------------//`

replace

```
openWarningDialog = function () {

  var dialogContent = "<div id='idletimer_warning_dialog'><p>" + currentConfig.dialogText + "</p><p style='display:inline'>" + currentConfig.dialogTimeRemaining + ": <div style='display:inline' id='countdownDisplay'></div></p></div>";

  $(dialogContent).dialog({
    buttons: [{
      text: currentConfig.dialogStayLoggedInButton,
      click: function () {
        destroyWarningDialog();
        stopDialogTimer();
        startIdleTimer();
      }
    },
      {
        text: currentConfig.dialogLogOutNowButton,
        click: function () {
          logoutUser();
        }
      }
      ],
    closeOnEscape: false,
    modal: true,
    title: currentConfig.dialogTitle,
    open: function () {
      $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
    }
  });

  countdownDisplay();

  document.title = currentConfig.dialogTitle;

  if (currentConfig.sessionKeepAliveTimer) {
    stopKeepSessionAlive();
  }
};
```

with

```
openWarningDialog = function () {

  var dialogContent = "<div id='idletimer_warning_dialog'><p>" + currentConfig.dialogText + "</p><p style='display:inline'>" + currentConfig.dialogTimeRemaining + ": <div style='display:inline' id='countdownDisplay'></div></p></div>";

  $(dialogContent).dialog({
    buttons: [{
      text: currentConfig.dialogStayLoggedInButton,
      click: function () {
        destroyWarningDialog();
        stopDialogTimer();
        startIdleTimer();
      }
    }],
    closeOnEscape: false,
    modal: true,
    title: currentConfig.dialogTitle,
    open: function () {
      $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
    }
  });

  countdownDisplay();

  document.title = currentConfig.dialogTitle;

  if (currentConfig.sessionKeepAliveTimer) {
    stopKeepSessionAlive();
  }
};
```

Save your modified code file with a new name (example: jquery-idleTimer-no-logoutnow-button.js), and upload this file to your server.

Next load your modified code. Look at the example file for how to load the required javascript files: https://github.com/JillElaine/jquery-idleTimeout/blob/master/example.html

Replace

```
<script src="/js/store.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-idleTimeout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="/js/store.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-idleTimeout-no-logoutnow-button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I guess this Timeout dialog won't work if we have different Querystring Parameters for the Same Page..like say (abc.aspx?id=param1) and (abc.aspx?id=param2) it is displaying two different dialogues for these two pages on two diff tabs independently. Can you pls comment on this..?

Comment: Hi Jill, In your plug in , The log out dialog is displayed if user is idle for some time, But the KeepaliveTimer and KeepAlive URL will keep on pinging the Server making session never Timeout. Then what's the point of displaying the info to user that he is about to logout? Secondly, This SetAlive URL needs to be used only when User clicks the Stay logged in Button and thus making it mandatory. Any inputs on how to resolve this?

Comment: Also, You are not pinging the Server on Activity Events in the IdleTimeout.min.js , How can the Server know the client side Events have taken place like mouse move etc.. Can you help me in letting Server know of Client Side Activities as we give in Configurations? The Code looks much much difficult to understand... unfortunately.....:( It would be better if you can spot to some useful resource to use it....explaining its usage. if you can please.

Comment: In your first comment, the plugin will work across multiple pages within the same domain. It does not matter what querystring params, as long as the pages are all within the same domain. If the user has been idle, a warning dialog appears on all tabs and pages within the domain. If the user clicks "Stay Logged In", the warning dialog will disappear on all tabs and pages. This is because of 'store.js' which allows all tabs and pages to stay in synch.

Comment: In your second comment, the plugin pings the server (keepalive) only if you configure the plugin to do so. The plugin will ping the server as long as the user is active. If the warning dialog appears, the plugin stops pinging the server. If the user clicks the "Stay Logged In" button, the plugin will again start pinging the server.

Comment: In your third comment, the plugin does not ping the server whenever it detects user activity. Instead, the plugin pings the server (if you configure it to do so) at regular intervals (default: every 10 minutes), as long as the user is active. This minimizes network traffic while keeping the server session alive. The server does not 'know' the user has moved the mouse; the server sees only page requests to know the user is still active. The plugin's server pings are  'get' requests for a page. Read the code in jquery-idleTimeout-for-testing.js for better understanding.